# ActionScript: Number.toExponential returns incorrect results for some values

Tags: actionscript-3, floating-point

I found at least two numbers for which ActionScript's Number.toExponential(20) returns incorrect results.

The most obvious value is 0.

```
trace(Number(0).toExponential(20)); // 0.00000000000000000000e-16
trace(Number(0).toExponential(2));  // 0.00e-16
trace(Number(0).toExponential(1));  // 0.0e-16
trace(Number(0).toExponential(0));  // 1e-15 - even worse!
```

I've made a class Double for playing around with Numbers (which are IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating point format numbers). It takes a Number and extracts all the bits into sign, bits and significand (the latter is printed including the implicit leading bit), or can generate a Number provided sign, bits and significand. There are methods to get the next and prior nearest representable numbers.
Here's what 0 looks like internally:

```
[Double number=0.00000000000000000000e-16 sign=1 exponent=-1023 isZero
significand=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
```

The other incorrect results are the nearest representable Number greater than Number.MAX_VALUE / 2 and Number.MAX_VALUE / 4.

```
// Number.MAX_VALUE / 2.
trace(Number(8.98846567431157854072e+307).toExponential(20)); // 8.98846567431157854072e+307
// Nearest representable Number greater than Number.MAX_VALUE / 2. Printed incorrectly!
trace(Number(8.98846567431157953864e+307).toExponential(20)); // 0.e+327
// A Number two ULPs greater than Number.MAX_VALUE / 2.
trace(Number(8.98846567431158153448e+307).toExponential(20)); // 8.98846567431158153448e+307
// Nearest representable Number greater than Number.MAX_VALUE / 4. Printed incorrectly!
trace(Number(4.49423283715578976932e+307).toExponential(20)); // 0.e+327
```

Here's what these 4 numbers look like internally:

```
[Double number=8.98846567431157854072e+307 sign=1 exponent=1022 
significand=11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111]
[Double number=0.e+327 sign=1 exponent=1023 
significand=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
[Double number=8.98846567431158153448e+307 sign=1 exponent=1023 
significand=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001]
[Double number=0.e+327 sign=1 exponent=1022 
significand=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
```

So far all three numbers that are printed incorrectly have a 0 significand (with implicit leading 1), and the exponent values of 1023 (Emax for normal numbers), 1022 (Emax - 1), or -1023 (special exponent value for ±zero and subnormal numbers, Emin - 1).

Looks like toExponent doesn't correctly handle at least these three cases
. Are there any other numbers that would print incorrectly?

Trying to check if toExponential would produce correct results with other precision values.

```
trace(Number(8.98846567431157953864e+307).toExponential(2)); // 0.e+309
trace(Number(8.98846567431157953864e+307).toExponential(1)); // 0.e+308
trace(Number(8.98846567431157953864e+307).toExponential(0)); // 1e+308 - less bad!
```

If anyone interested in my Double class I will post it. I've also written faster implementations next(x:Number) and prior(x:Number) functions which work pretty fast without messing with internal bits of the numbers.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: if you want math precision don't use Flash that much is clear and has been for many years. Mathlab has nothing to fear from Flash.

Comment: @BotMaster that much was clear, however I'm making a scientific calculator mobile app, I aim it to be cross-platform, and Flash (here, Adobe AIR for mobile) is the platform I've been developing in for many years now. My plan is closely emulating the behavior of Casio FX scientific calculators, their hardware is hardly more accurate than Flash.